# Unexpected behavior of sprintf with i32/u32

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, sketch, tinygps

I'm trying to build a string of characters from several elements given by the [TinyGPS++ library](http://arduiniana.org/libraries/tinygpsplus/) with the use of sprintf().

This is my code making the string and printing it in the serial monitor.

```
char posmsg[100], lat[14+1], lon[14+1];

void sendString(){
  //- convert lat/lon
  dtostrf(gps.location.lat(), 10,6, lat);
  dtostrf(gps.location.lng(), 10,6, lon); 

  //- sprintf the string
  sprintf(posmsg, "$%4d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d,%s,%s,%i,%i,%i,%i,%i$",
          gps.date.year(),gps.date.month(),gps.date.day(),
          gps.time.hour(), gps.time.minute(), gps.time.second(),
          lat, lon,
          gps.speed.value(), gps.course.value(), gps.altitude.value(),
          gps.satellites.value(), gps.hdop.value()
        );

  Serial.println("--------------------");
  Serial.println(posmsg);
  Serial.println("--------------------");

  Serial.print("Speed:");
  Serial.println(gps.speed.value());
  Serial.print("Course:");Serial.println(gps.course.value());
  Serial.print("Height:");Serial.println(gps.altitude.value());
  Serial.print("Sats:");Serial.println(gps.satellites.value());
  Serial.print("HDOP:");Serial.println(gps.hdop.value());
  Serial.println("--------------------");
}
```

This is the result and what I expect... (spaces added for readability)

```
 Result:
 --------------------
 $2014-06-24 15:17:11,  51.xxxxxx,   5.xxxxxx, 2, 0, 4964, 0, 3660$
 --------------------
 Speed:2
 Course:4964
 Height:3660
 Sats:8
 HDOP:110
 --------------------

 Expected:
 --------------------
 $2014-06-24 15:17:11,  51.xxxxxx,   5.xxxxxx, 2, 4964, 3660, 8, 110$
 --------------------
```

So in the end of the string the numbers get displaced...

According to [the documentation](http://arduiniana.org/libraries/tinygpsplus/) the type of the variables are all integers or unsigned integers, but the sprintf messes things up.

```
 gps.speed.value(); // Raw speed in 100ths of a knot (i32)
 gps.course.value(); // Raw course in 100ths of a degree (i32)
 gps.altitude.value(); // Raw altitude in centimeters (i32)
 gps.satellites.value(); // Number of satellites in use (u32)
 gps.hdop.value(); // Horizontal Dim. of Precision (100ths-i32)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ints and unsigned ints are 16 bits on AVR ATmegas.
So while the argument passed is a 32-bit value, sprintf() is expecting a 16 bit value.  The stack is packed with twice as much data as needed.

From the "2,0,4964" bit, it looks like it taking part of the previous/next parameter during processing, which makes me think this even more.

You need to use *long* types, e.g.: %ld or %li and %lu